# How do you query for child elements while iterating through elements in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm able to get the parent element but I unable to successfully get the child elements and their attributes. I'd like to be able to extract the id in the input element below and put it in the array called links.

I tried this

```js
var links = [];

$(".sportmenu li").each(function(i, item) {
  links.push(
    $(item).children("input")[0].id
  );
});
console.log(links);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sportmenu ui-listview">
  <li class="table">
    <span class="fav-box table-cell">
          <input type="checkbox" id="TOP_SPORT-246712-Serie B" class="star" readonly="" value="on">
          <label></label>
        </span>
    <div class="competition-info">
      <span class="table-cell">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-link">
              <span class="league">Serie B</span>
      </a>
      </span>
      <span class="val-box table-cell">
            <span class="val">2</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would not suggest that you have spaces in your id´s

Comment: Not my markup. Doing scraping.

Comment: the input is not a direct child of the li which is why your query is not working

Comment: @Pete thanks for the insight. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` and `attr`:

```js
var links = [];

$(".sportmenu li").each(function(i, item) {
 links.push(
   $(item).find("input").attr('id')
  );
});

console.log(links)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sportmenu ui-listview">
  <li class="table">
    <span class="fav-box table-cell">
      <input type="checkbox" id="TOP_SPORT-246712-Serie B" class="star" readonly="" value="on">
      <label></label>
    </span>
    <div class="competition-info">
      <span class="table-cell">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-link">
          <span class="league">Serie B</span>
        </a>
      </span>
      <span class="val-box table-cell">
        <span class="val">2</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, just change `.children()` to `.find()`:

```js
var links = [];

$(".sportmenu li").each(function(i, item) {
  links.push(
    $(item).find("input")[0].id
  );
});

console.log(links);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sportmenu ui-listview">
  <li class="table">
    <span class="fav-box table-cell">
      <input type="checkbox" id="TOP_SPORT-246712-Serie B" class="star" readonly="" value="on">
      <label></label>
    </span>
    <div class="competition-info">
      <span class="table-cell">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-link">
          <span class="league">Serie B</span>
        </a>
      </span>
      <span class="val-box table-cell">
        <span class="val">2</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`.children` is for direct childs, whereas `.find()` will find any level child.

Docs:
https://api.jquery.com/children/
https://api.jquery.com/find/

Also, note that your `id`s shouldn't contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `map`

And on your `id`s should not contain any spaces as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/31773673#31773673).

```js
var ids = $(".sportmenu li input").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="sportmenu ui-listview">
  <li class="table">
    <span class="fav-box table-cell">
      <input type="checkbox" id="TOP_SPORT-246712-Serie_A" class="star" readonly="" value="on">
      <label></label>
    </span>
    <div class="competition-info">
      <span class="table-cell">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-link">
          <span class="league">Serie B</span>
      </a>
      </span>
      <span class="val-box table-cell">
        <span class="val">2</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="table">
    <span class="fav-box table-cell">
      <input type="checkbox" id="TOP_SPORT-246712-Serie_B" class="star" readonly="" value="on">
      <label></label>
    </span>
    <div class="competition-info">
      <span class="table-cell">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-link">
          <span class="league">Serie B</span>
      </a>
      </span>
      <span class="val-box table-cell">
        <span class="val">2</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Doc: [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
var result = $(".sportmenu li input").map(function() {
return this.id
}).get()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sportmenu ui-listview">
  <li class="table">
    <span class="fav-box table-cell">
      <input type="checkbox" id="TOP_SPORT-246712-Serie B" class="star" readonly="" value="on">
      <label></label>
    </span>
    <div class="competition-info">
      <span class="table-cell">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-link">
          <span class="league">Serie B</span>
        </a>
      </span>
      <span class="val-box table-cell">
        <span class="val">2</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```